# Programatically getting printer queue at the printer

Tags: c#, windows, printing

I print a lot of documents to a printer using Foxit Reader. At some point the printer begins to "optimize" the document queue, screwing up my print order (and there is no option to deactivate it).

So, what I need is a feedback from the printer telling me "I got 10 documents in my queue" or "I still have 100 pages to print" so I can wait with further print commands.

The print spooler doesn't buffer my documents so querying it doesn't help me any further.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Probably,what have you tried? There could be several ways, have you tried any? Search for windows printer related API's? A quick google seach point me to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @bradbury9: The documents are not buffered in the print spooler of windows, they are buffered on the printer itself. Therefore there is no use of querying the window print spooler.
What other ways are there? I don't know of any. And googling really didn't help me either.

Comment: One stupid method - you can scan the spooler directory and start new document when it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out there is something called [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) where you can query quite a lot of different devices inside your network.

And I learned, that there is a library called [SnmpSharpNet (also available on Nuget)](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com) which helps you querying data - the simplest way would look like this (querying the total number of printed pages):

```
SimpleSnmp snmp = new SimpleSnmp("192.168.1.3", "public");

if (!snmp.Valid)
    return;

Dictionary<Oid, AsnType> result = snmp.Get(SnmpVersion.Ver1, new string[] { ".1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.4.1.1" });
```

If you want to query different data google for "OID".